# How can blood vessels or bronchi be divided into separate branches?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt2Pa.png)

When we get a picture or three-dimensional image of a blood vessel, how can we divide the blood vessel into small branches?

The current thinking is as follows:

Through the skeletonization function, the image of blood vessels or bronchus is skeletonized (image. morphology. skeletonize_3d), and then whether there is a node (multiple branch convergence points) is judged, and then separated from the node. But I don't know how to implement the node.

Does python have a packaged package that can be called?

I want to know is there any package can use?

Answer (score 0):

The [skan](https://skeleton-analysis.org/stable/) library is designed for this, though it may not have every feature you need. (Disclaimer: I am the main author of the library.)